# Moving the default folders(.AndroidStudio2.X and .gradle ) to D disk:

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to move Installed AndroidStudio from C: disk to another.
I've successfully(by standard way) `.android` folder, `sdk` folder(with it's environment variable) and installation path.  However, I cant handle these ones:

```
c:\users\user\.AndroidStudio2.2
c:\users\user\.gradle
```

when I move these folders to `d:\myfolder` and changing every occurrence of  `c:\users\user\.AndroidStudio2.2` to `d:\myfolder\.AndroidStudio2.2` (with [TextCrawler](https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/tcdownloads.html)), and changing `.gradle` location in AndroidStudio, it doesnt help.
In `C:\user\user` there is still created (upon running AStudio) `.AndroidStudio2.2` folder. And running Emulator causes errors, because it cant find anything options in `C:\users......`

plus, I have uncommented and set the `path` values (in `installation/bin/idea.properties`) to `d:\myfolder`, but still no help.

Comment: If you use the `-windows.zip` Android Studio download, it should be completely portable. Gradle, on the other hand, might need separate configuration.

Comment: can you tell me negative sides of being portable (so, positive sides of being full-installed)?

Comment: The SDK is not included in the portable download. The only positive I can think of for the full-installer is that everything is more-or-less included and setup for you, e.g. SDK is included and environment variables are set correctly

Answer (score 2):

Having dome something similar in the past, I find that moving drives on most software applications is still a big pain. However, I found that creating symlinks was helpful, as the software will "think" it's accessing the files at a location, but in reality they are stored in another.

I successfully did this [in the past with Visual Studio](https://www.placona.co.uk/1196/dotnet/installing-visual-studio-on-a-different-drive/) and the concept is pretty much the same with Android Studio. You need to create a symlink as follows:

```
mklink /J "d:\myfolder\.AndroidStudio2.2" "c:\users\user\.AndroidStudio2.2"
```

Now when Android studio read or write the contents in `c:\users\user\.AndroidStudio2.2`, it will be in reality going to your d drive, which provided that it's accessible by the c drive, should make it all work.

You should be able to do that with the other folders as well. The benefit of doing it this way is that you're not constrained to the path the file is stored, which means that if you change computers or decide to store everything on the c drive again, you can just remove the symlink.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: hm, interesting solution... However, I wished there was standard way available.

Comment: "it will be in reality going to your d drive" -- I don't think so... You linked the C drive directory to the D drive, so the files are still read from and contained within C, no?